# Define multiple CSS files for each page using Struts 2 with Tiles

Tags: css, jsp, iterator, struts2, tiles

I'm creating a web application using the Struts 2 (2.3.4.1) and the tiles (2.0.6) framework. My `tiles.xml` uses the typical base definition where other definitions inherit from:

```
<!-- SHARED LAYOUT --> 
<definition name="sharedLayout" template="/shared/jsp/Base.jsp">
   <put-attribute name="pageHeader" value="/shared/jsp/Header.jsp"/>
   <put-attribute name="pageContent" value=""/>
   <put-attribute name="pageFooter" value="/shared/jsp/Footer.jsp"/>
   <put-attribute name="pageCss" value="" type="string"/>
</definition>

<!-- INDEX --> 
<definition name="/Index.tiles" extends="sharedLayout">
    <put-attribute name="pageContent" value="/shared/jsp/Index.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="pageCss" value="{'/css/index.css','/css/index_extra.css','/css/index_buttons.css'}" type="string"/>
</definition>
```

I use the tiles attribute `pageCss` to define an array of CSS files the index page should use like this:

```
<put-attribute name="pageCss" value="{'/css/index.css','/css/index_extra.css','/css/index_buttons.css'}" type="string"/>
```

In the `<head></head>` section of my `base.jsp`, I use the following code to turn that string into correct `<link>'s`:

```
<s:set var="pageCssArray"><tiles:getAsString name='pageCss'/></s:set>
<s:iterator value="%{#pageCssArray}">
    <s:set var="CurrentCss"><s:property/></set>
    <link type="text/css" href="<s:url value='%{#CurrentCss}'/>" rel="stylesheet"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as intended. Rather than the iterator looping over the array elements, it thinks the array is one big string instead of an array and it will only iterate over 1 element, because it thinks its one element rather than an array. Thus instead of 3 `<link>`, I get only 1 `<link>` with an url that is seriously malformed (because its is simply the string as defined in `tiles.xml`). Why is the iterator not treating the strings as a proper array, I did use the `%{}` notation?

So what I need is a way to define any amount of CSS files in the tiles definitions, and for the JSP page to dynamically create the appropriate links to each of these files.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable using a `value` attribute.

```
<s:set var="pageCssArray" value="{'/css/index.css','/css/index_extra.css','/css/index_buttons.css'}">
```

and use it in jsp, or parse this string like in my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23395431/573032).